# why a closed socket can not be reused to connect to a server?

Tags: python, sockets, file-descriptor

First, I close the client of socket connection, then I want to reuse it to connect to the same socket server, but it reports "Bad file descripotor". Why can not do this?

```
>>> import socket
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sock.connect(('localhost', 8080))
>>> sock.send(b'hello')
5
>>> sock.close()
>>> sock
<socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>
>>> sock.connect(('localhost', 8080))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: That's just the way sockets work, they can only be used once. Create a new socket each time.

Comment: Sometimes it's good to look at docs: [`socket.socket()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.close), [`socket.close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.close).

Comment: @OlvinRoght Where does it say anything about not being able to reopen it?

Comment: @Barmar, "Close a socket file descriptor." which means that it's in fact destructor of socket object. You can't reuse object which you've destroyed before.

Comment: so in this case, I need to create a new socket client ? And keep alone the old one or delete it?

Comment: The garbage collector will deal with it if you reuse the variable.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thank you